# Default priority of thread with SCHED_FIFO

Tags: linux, default, thread-priority

What is the default priority of thread with SCHED_FIFO policy in Linux? The range is 0-99.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [*Red Hat Enterprise MRG 1.3
Realtime Reference Guide*](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_MRG/1.3/html-single/Realtime_Reference_Guide/index.html#chap-Realtime_Reference_Guide-Priorities_and_policies), there is no default priority value for the SCHED_FIFO policy.

You have to set the priority when you set the policy to SCHED_FIFO.

Priority values:

```
Policy        Default    Lowest   Highest
SCHED_FIFO                  1       99
SCHED_RR                    1       99
SCHED_OTHER     0         -20       19
```